# How to start windows sharepoint services web application from status "upgrade" and without a link to start in action?

Tags: sharepoint

How to start windows sharepoint services web application from status "upgrade" and without a link to start in action?

:39083/_admin/server.aspx

create web application in step 4 comment is required, but not executed services

status is upgrade, action do not have link

How to start this?

Comment: were you doing something and got this exception?

Comment: kindly open services console using service.msc command and check status of windows sharepoint timer job and windows sharepoint service administration job status

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint services timer, tracing , administration services in services.msc are open

Job tab, i press finish upgrade, the status is working,

This is not an exception, after a long time waiting the status is the same

Comment: I do not log in and close browser so i use another name

Comment: Admin, Timer and tracing are started in services.msc

Comment: may be a absurd question to ask but just to conform are you starting the services on same server where central admin is installed or any other server on farm

Comment: one more thing what are diffrent windows hot fixes applied on your server recentely where you are trying to start this service